# Deploying test playbook with Docker to Ubuntu image. Hi, anyone knows why that error came up, I couldn't find solution over Google

Tags: image, docker, ansible, containers

```
[root@prdx-ansible docker_ansible]# ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory.txt

PLAY [Deploy web app] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [target1]
ok: [target2]

TASK [Install all dependencies] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: Updating cache and auto-installing missing dependency: python3-apt
fatal: [target1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "'/usr/bin/apt-mark manual python python-setuptools python-dev build-essential python-pip python-mysqldb' failed: E: Couldn't create temporary file to work with /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease - mkstemp (28: No space left on device)\nE: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.\n", "rc": 100, "stderr": "E: Couldn't create temporary file to work with /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease - mkstemp (28: No space left on device)\nE: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.\n", "stderr_lines": ["E: Couldn't create temporary file to work with /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease - mkstemp (28: No space left on device)", "E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
fatal: [target2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "'/usr/bin/apt-mark manual python python-setuptools python-dev build-essential python-pip python-mysqldb' failed: E: Couldn't create temporary file to work with /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease - mkstemp (28: No space left on device)\nE: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.\n", "rc": 100, "stderr": "E: Couldn't create temporary file to work with /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease - mkstemp (28: No space left on device)\nE: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.\n", "stderr_lines": ["E: Couldn't create temporary file to work with /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease - mkstemp (28: No space left on device)", "E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
target1                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
target2                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

here is playbook

```
[root@prdx-ansible docker_ansible]# cat playbook.yml
- name: Deploy web app
  hosts: target1,target2
  tasks:
    - name: Install all dependencies
      package:
        name: ['python', 'python-setuptools', 'python-dev', 'build-essential', 'python-pip', 'python-mysqldb']
        state: present

    - name: Install MySQL database
      apt: name={{ item }} state=installed
      with_items:
      - mysql-server
      - mysql-client

    - name: Start the database service
      service:
        name: mysql
        state: statred
        enabled: yes

    - name: Create database
      mysql_db: name=emploee_db state=present

    - name: Create DB user
      mysql_user:
        name: db_user
        password: Passw0rd
        priv: '*.*:ALL'
        state: present
        host: '%'

    - name: Install Flask
      pip:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        state: present
      with_items:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Couldn't create temporary file to work with [..] mkstemp (28: No space left on device)
```

Your target server disk seems to be full. Check with `df -h` how much space you have left. You may have to run `apt-get clean` and similar commands to clean up some space.

Comment: Thank You, it worked for me, why I didn't pay attention for that Error, lol, Thank You again

Answer (score 0):

```
[root@prdx-ansible docker_ansible]# ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory.txt

PLAY [Deploy web app] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [target1]
ok: [target2]

TASK [Install all dependencies] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: Updating cache and auto-installing missing dependency: python3-apt
changed: [target2]
changed: [target1]

TASK [Install MySQL database] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Invoking "apt" only once while using a loop via squash_actions is deprecated. Instead of using a loop to supply multiple items and specifying `name:
"{{ item }}"`, please use `name: ['mysql-server', 'mysql-client']` and remove the loop. This feature will be removed in version 2.11. Deprecation warnings can be disabled
by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Invoking "apt" only once while using a loop via squash_actions is deprecated. Instead of using a loop to supply multiple items and specifying `name:
"{{ item }}"`, please use `name: ['mysql-server', 'mysql-client']` and remove the loop. This feature will be removed in version 2.11. Deprecation warnings can be disabled
by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
changed: [target2] => (item=[u'mysql-server', u'mysql-client'])
changed: [target1] => (item=[u'mysql-server', u'mysql-client'])

TASK [Start the database service] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [target2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 172.17.03 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: 1: sudo: not found\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 127}
fatal: [target1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 172.17.02 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: 1: sudo: not found\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 127}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
target1                    : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
target2                    : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0





NOW I GOT THIS ERROR!!
```